# Should questions regarding Project Euler be allowed?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, etiquette, spoilers

I've been active on [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) for a while.
A couple of things from the FAQ in the main page are:

About search engines:

> I solved it by using a search engine, does that matter?
>
> Making use of the internet to research a problem is to be encouraged
>   as there could be hidden treasures of mathematics to be discovered
>   beneath the surface of many of these problems. However, there is a
>   fine line between researching ideas and using the answer you found on
>   another website. If you photocopy a crossword solution then what have
>   you achieved?

About posting on their public forum:

> Also please note that your posts will be visible to all members and
>   you are requested to be thoughtful in not posting anything that might
>   explicitly give away how to solve a particular problem.

Lately I've seen people asking about Project Euler on SO, which doesn't sit well with me, for the above reasons. A Quick search shows more:

- [Program ignoring for loop bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25339690/1698987)
- [Project Euler Problem 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7000168/1698987)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/7301832/1698987

Shall we remove the questions, flag them, or just ignore it, risking depriving people the joy and achievement of figuring things out for themselves?

Answer (score 19):

It's not on us to enforce the terms and conditions of another website, so if you flag these, moderators will decline your flags.

As far as I'm concerned, if the question asked would be a viable, on-topic programming question without the context of it being on Project Euler, I have no problem with it being here. This applies to every other programming competition or challenge site out there.

Comment: Cleaning up the "project euler" from the tag / questions then ?

Comment: Related [destroy the spot tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181970/destroy-the-spoj-tag) on MSE.