# Burninate Project Euler

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The wiki for [project-euler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-euler) says:

> **Please be aware** that the purpose of Project Euler is to encourage people to think and learn so publishing the solution or working code would render this process useless.

Yeah… no. The tag wiki tells answerers to basically treat SO as a forum for Project Euler, the tag seems to suggest that answers should just be hints… (which isn't a good use of a tag)

We should burninate [this meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-euler) (1249 questions). And a lot of the questions can be closed/deleted.

Obviously questions that were inspired by Project Euler and created in the solving of their very real-wordly problems that happen to also apply to other problems unrelated to Project Euler which would not benefit from a tag that noted their "inspiration" (or for that matter any mention [or link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276402/2371861) to Project Euler) would be totally on-topic.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274528/should-we-add-project-euler-to-everything-from-project-euler and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269920/should-questions-regarding-project-euler-be-allowed

Comment: Yeah no people should not be publishing working code, or yeah no questions about Project Euler shouldn't be asked at all?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Neither, see edit.

Comment: We can't prohibit people from asking about it. Personally I couldn't care less about it. But the tag shouldn't be there, just the same way you don't tag questions with `coursera` or any other source of learning.

Comment: I don't see any reason why SO should be expected to enforce somebody else's rules. SO is a place for complete answers. If they don't like SO's own rules, they should recommend another mechanism, or provide their own. I'd support removing the tag.

Comment: Scrolling through the tag it looks like a bunch of "do my work for me" types of questions, which is inevitable for a site like project euler. You're either going to get experts who know what they're doing, or people who don't and spam forums with "I need help".

Comment: The meta tag should probably go, but it's not SO's job to make sure no one publishes solutions. People using Project Euler are free to just not look up the solutions in the first place.

Comment: I also support this request.

Comment: Barely started looking at questions with this tag, but the 1% sampled so far are all bad.

Comment: I am the one who lately added [project-euler] tag to around 100 questions so now there are 1352 of them. But now I see all the context and have to admit that you are right and this tag should be destroyed. I proposed burnination also to '4clojure' tag

Comment: @rtruszk: Please post your experience as an answer. So for what reasons should the tag have been destroyed? Because most questions were low-quality, because it attracted VLQ new users, because it wasn't a legitimate meta-tag, or why?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

After some [Python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) denizens [got itchy about programming contest meta tags](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/21092582#21092582), we went ahead and started cleaning. The [project-euler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-euler) tag was a natural progression once we started.

After two days of coordinated retagging, closing and deleting, now properly burninated are:

[programming-competitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-competitions), [acm-icpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acm-icpc), [ai-challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ai-challenge), [codechef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codechef), [code-kata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-kata), [codeforces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codeforces), [coding-dojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-dojo), [facebook-hacker-cup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-hacker-cup), [google-code-jam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-code-jam), [hackerrank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hackerrank), [ioccc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ioccc), [ioi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ioi), [informatics-olympiad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/informatics-olympiad), [netflix-competition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netflix-competition), [ruby-koans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-koans), [spoj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spoj), [topcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/topcoder), [uva-online-judge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uva-online-judge) and [ideone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ideone)

We are left with <strike>2</strike> <strike>1</strike> no questions that are holding [programming-contest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-contest) alive; the following two remaining posts were deleted:

- <strike>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631312/how-to-get-better-at-programming-contests</strike> — *deleted*
- <strike>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561301/overview-and-news-of-about-coding-competitions</strike> — *deleted*

There *was* one remaining [project-euler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-euler) question:

- <strike>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137178/project-euler-resources</strike> — *retagged*, so [project-euler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-euler) is gone!

Yes, we managed to clear the site of **21** different meta tags, perhaps more as the tags burned I may have forgotten to note a smaller one here or there.

Since [project-euler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-euler) is gone, we can declare it:

[image: tag burninated]

♫♩ Burninating the countryside ♪♬ burninating the peasants ♫♩ burninating all the peoples ♬♪ in the thatch roofed cottages! ♬♩

*Wicked dueling guitar-solos*.

Comment: Please tell us the reasoning for deleting these tags. I don't see any reasons why the (majority) bad questions could have been deleted, the duplicates merged, and the good questions let stand. What % of the questions were bad? 90+%? How about a beta site "Programming Challenges", this would shunt all the traffic over there and away from here (which most of you seem to want), while letting good contributors get started in the SO network?

Comment: @smci: because it *doesn't matter* where the problem came from. There are no experts in specific competitions. The same problem on two different sites, or entirely outside of a competition, still requires the same answer, the `euler` tag wouldn't help you distinguish between different questions.

Comment: @smci: also see [When to burninate](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/239190); contest site tags are *meta tags*, they don't meaningfully describe the problem, only the context in which the problem was found.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: of course there are experts. Some questions are algorithmic, some are more language-specific, some will be about data structures and efficiency. In a non-ideal world, it totally *does matter* where the problem came from, since that defines a context of what the user might know in the algorithm and language. For novice programmers, meta tags do meaningfully describe the problem; challenge-specific topics could be used on a sister site "Programming Challenges". It would offload SO, so everybody wins.

Comment: @smci: This is about *this site*, not a sister site. There are specific tags for each of those points, so just use *those tags*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: except it's grossly unreasonable to expect novice programmers to accurately tag their question, or even have the vocabulary to understand how. After they learn that, they're not novices. I totally get that plenty of you want those questions off SO, but is a beta site proposal a good idea in people's collective opinion? That *is* still tangentially relevant to SO, because its very existence keeps those questions off here.

Comment: @smci: I have no opinion on the viability of another site. I don't see how not having complete knowledge of tags (which is *fine*) necessitates these metatags. If you want to discuss this further, I suggest you open a new Meta post, comments are not really the place for extended discussion.

Comment: Before opening such a Meta post, I want to understand from you all how to phrase it, so I don't get instantly napalmed.

Comment: @smci: Sorry, that's not something I can help with.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: it's entirely something you and the others can comment on. Too much snark here about how awful the questions are, and not much comment about what to do with the good 10% of them and their novice users.

Comment: [tag:ruby-koans] is back from the dead. and so is [hackerrank](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359866/the-challenge-of-burninating-hackerrank)

Comment: @SurajRao: thanks, dead and dead again.

Answer (score 20):

I don't see anything on the [project euler website](https://projecteuler.net/about) that *prohibits* people from posting answers on the web. In fact, if people wanted solutions, they could easily [google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=project+euler+solutions) and be done with the day. There's no "terms of conditions" that I can find like this [answer suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269921/3920237). It may be a different story on the forums, however, you need to register an account in order to visit it. Outside visitors who don't have an account therefore cannot possibly know the rules, forum culture and expect to know to behave if the main website doesn't have an explicit terms of conditions.

Secondly, MichaelT makes a compelling [argument](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274534/3920237) regarding meta tags:

> The project euler tag (or spoj) says nothing about the actual problem
>   but rather the context it is in.
>
> A good question is a good question regardless of its relationship to
>   homework, project euler, spoj, or any on line code contest. On the
>   other hand, a question tagged with such is often used as an 'excuse'
>   as to why it exists at all - trying to make up for poor quality with
>   "but its a real problem in this website."
>
> This tag should go the way of homework.

Take a look at [kr-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kr-c) tag, an obsolete book which predates the ANSI standard. Despite the fact that the book is over 20 years old, we still have people coming here with questions like [K&R exercise - just need someone to check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669003/kr-exercise-just-need-someone-to-check)  which have a shitty title, demonstrate no research effort and consists of a code dump. It's *technically* mutually exclusive with the [C](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) tag because modern compilers don't support pre-standard C and most people will be programming in C89/90/ANSI mode by default, unless they're using some ancient compiler like Turbo C. If you were to remove the C tag, like MichaelT's answer suggest, the tag serves no purpose.

It's not necessarily a bad thing to be practicing exercises from the book, but to use the tag as an excuse for a crap question is the issue at hand here.

On the other hand, project euler has interesting puzzles and generates interesting discussion on *their* website, but Stack Overflow unfortunately is at the ass-end of it and attracts people who want a quick and easy answer rather than to solve the puzzle intellectually. It's perfectly possible to have interesting, well-researched questions but I just don't see that on the tag. I think if the tag were to disappear, it would be more immediate that "project euler" adds nothing of value to the question and that a crap question is a crap question.

Comment: [tag:kr-c] is a really bad example. Yes, it's a tag for questions about pre-standard C, but so what? It might be severely outdated, and I *really* don't want to program anything in that dialect, but we also don't kill old versions of C# (and we even have [tag:cobol]). If you want to make a good argument, rather go after [tag:knr] and [tag:kernighan-and-ritchie], which seem to be about the book.