# Derail [railstutorial.org]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[railstutorial.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/railstutorial.org) is about questions stemming from confusion with the (apparently wildly popular, or perhaps merely extremely confusing?) RoR tutorial at the site of the same name, by Michael Hartl. But there is no sense in which these questions can really be unique to the tutorial in question: they're just Rails questions that happen to be *triggered by reading* some particular article about Rails. So as far as I can tell, this is a meta tag..

But it's an awfully popular one: it has 848 questions and *97 followers*, although how many of those are using it as an impromptu honeypot for bad questions I'm uncertain.

I'm pretty sure there's been agreement that tags of this nature should be burninated before, but I can't find even a single question on M.SO *or* M.SE about burninating Hartl-related tags. So I'm not sure what the deal is there.

Comment: you are looking for this one [Burninate Project Euler](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275935)

Comment: @Braiam: More or less, although I was pretty sure Hartl's stuff *specifically* had also been the subject at one time.

Comment: I totally agree that this tag should be gone, although I have to say, it was nice that every single problem I had working through that tutorial had been answered on Stack Overflow with a title like "[Error message] in Chapter 7.3 of Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial". All I had to do was Google the error message, the chapter, and the word "Hartl", and there was my answer.

Comment: @tsleyson I think that would have worked even without this tag. (Cool though!)

Comment: Is there any case where it's appropriate to name a tag after a website?  I can't think of one.

Comment: @Anko I used Google, so I didn't need the tag, but other people might have been looking just on SO, where the tag is useful. Again, I do agree that the tag should be gone, and people can still Google for the questions like I did.

Comment: @aroth: [tag:parse.com] stands out.

Comment: This qualifies as a meta tag, and [they're not appropriate here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Comment: it's both wildly popular and extremely confusing. win!