# What's the policy on creating tags for website names?

Tags: discussion, tags

What's the policy on creating tags for website names?

Existing examples: [parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse.com), [urbanairship.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urbanairship.com)

I ask because someone just made a tag and a corresponding tag wiki with the information:

> Livestream is the easiest way to broadcast your event live and/or watch live events. https://livestream.com/about"

Comment: Why the downvote? There's no priori, and I'm asking for a policy.

Comment: [Voting on Meta is different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254108/2564301) (although it's kind of a stretch to make it indicate: "Policy? Policy? I *disagree*!!")

Comment: @Jongware I would assume a downvote on a (non-leading) discussion question would mean "I don't think this is worth discussion"?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The fact that the tag is based on a website name is entirely a red herring: some such tags [are quite terrible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294548/derail-railstutorial-org), while others are perfectly legitimate. The deciding factor is whether the *website* has some relevance to the *programming environment*.

A site with an API standard of its own that has a lot of questions? Perfectly reasonable. A site that has its own language, framework, or platform that it allows users to run code on? Yeah, that will work.

A tutorial site? No. A site that some program needs to scrape? No.

A site that uses standardized metadata to offer a very limited subset of API-like functionality, as the sole current livestream.com example appears to indicate? Ehhhhhh not so much. There's not much that really appears to be about that site's unique programming traits; it's simply one site out of potentially hundreds or thousands using the same basic tags as any other site would to do the same thing. It's basically just a different type of scraping.

The real question, then, is whether there's a unique (or essentially unique) standard (or API definition, or whatever) *defined by the site in question* for their own purposes. That narrows things down, because there's then questions that have to do with the intricacies of that standard that might not apply to anything else. That's the point of a tag: to identify the common points of meaningful difference in programming.

Comment: "whether the website has some relevance to the programming environment" no the website, but a service they provide are unique to programming enviroment, otherwise, Facebook should not have a tag, while w3.org should.

Comment: @Braiam: That's what I meant; the fact that w3schools happens to be a website, or Facebook, is largely irrelevant; the main point is what common name is best associated with the unique programming environment in question. In some cases, that happens to look like a web domain name.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

[Looks like it's been sorted out](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/livestream.com/info); it doesn't read like a useless blurb.

My thoughts on the tag:  if there are genuine questions related to its API then I don't mind.  The question that *does* exist makes me feel a bit iffy...but so long as others actually post useful questions with the tag, I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: The excerpt is a little better, but the main wiki is still useless ad copy.