# A moan about [koans]

Tags: discussion, tags

Tag: [koans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/koans)

This tag was created today by a single user through suggested edits.

Does such a tag have value? A "koan" isn't a descriptor of anything about what the user is trying to achieve. I can't see what it does to help describe the question.

It looks like similar tags (e.g. [ruby-koans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-koans)) have existed in the past and been [removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler/284302#284302). Can we nip this one in the bud?

Comment: I left a comment for the creator of the tag and the edits to point out this post.

Comment: *Does such a tag have value?* More importantly, does it have a Buddha-nature?

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest we let it run for a while, just to make it easier to find more [questions that need to be closed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6892080/1288).

Comment: As if we have a hard time finding questions to close .....

Comment: @Bill I did flag that question, but then I thought "When will I get such an opportunity for a rhyming tag meta post again?"

Comment: Can we just make it a synonym for 无?

Comment: If people want koans I can highly recommend http://thecodelesscode.com/

Comment: I never heard about koans before...

Comment: @bob-theunholymetalmachine it's known in the Ruby community. It is likely linked to the fact that it started in Japan. This tag refers to http://rubykoans.com/ and is also the popular https://rubymonk.com Koan / programming association seems to precede Ruby though:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_koan

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚威视 I guess *rubykoans* is a pun about the *rubicon* (famous river in ancient Rome)

Comment: A moan about [koans]? Groan...

Comment: In R we have a 'fortunes'-package maintained by the Arch-Monk Zeileis.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Mu

Answer (score 29):

The description provided for the tag (emphasis mine):

> a (software) **koan is the term "used in reference to tutorials that exemplify edge case scenarios** or 'Aha! moments'. If you're learning a new software skill and feel the classical 'Hello World' examples are boring or to easy, then you should take a look at Koans."

That seems to be a meta tag the same way [[homework]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/can-we-now-discourage-the-use-of-and-burninate-the-homework-tag) and [[project-euler]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler) were.  It seems to refer to collections of practice problems, basically the same way project-euler did.  There's no added information that the tag can communicate that shouldn't already exist in the question.  Looking at the related tags so far, there are currently 0 overlapping tags on any koan question (other than koan).  So it's really not clear what the tag will be related to.

And looking at the approved edits so far, it seems that user is only adding the tag to post that *already contain* "koan" in the title or text of the question. There are currently [196 question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=koan%20is%3Aq)  for the search `koan is:q`.  Those posts could use *better titles* instead of a useless tag.

It should be perma-burned.

Comment: +1 - TL;DR: in the form of a haiku: Koan is meta tag; Burninate now with much haste;  Better blacklist tag.

Comment: I actually enumerated a list of koans in different languages that would be useful to a programmer learning beyond Hello World. Shouldn't there be a way to search for koan-related questions easily?

Comment: @pageman yes.  It's called google.  Koan does nothing to help SO organize its questions by subject matter.  It is a meta tag, and other tags will do a better job of describing the actual gotcha encountered within each koan.

Comment: @ryanyuyu can you suggest some search terms that would make my life easier vs. searching a meta-tag in SO?

Answer (score 7):

There were only 5 questions with tag [koans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/koans) when I went to look, and they were all older questions (mostly 2010-2013, IIRC).  There are now no such questions.

With the passage of a little time, the tag wiki <s>will disappear</s> has disappeared.  We should keep an eye on the tag for a day or two.

[image: ***TROGDOR***]