# Is it time for [codingbat] to fly away?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Look at the [codingbat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codingbat) tag:

> CodingBat is a free site of live coding problems to build coding skills in Java and Python.

I don't see how this tag can be useful to anyone, all the posts tagged with it don't have anything to do with the website itself.

In general, I really don't see how code-challenge tags can be helpful. Most of the posts tagged with them are really pure [language]  tag, the solution doesn't care about the website that the challenge came from. Do we really need these tags?

Examples:

- [How to replace a char in a string without using Replace() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33385715/how-to-replace-a-char-in-a-string-without-replace-method-java)
- [Having trouble with the mod operator; I'm not getting the result I'm expecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355641/having-trouble-with-codingbat-puzzle-on-mod-opperator)
- [Switching last two char in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32931789/why-wont-it-work-codingbat-lasttwo-switching-last-two-char-in-a-string-java)

I really don't care where the code came from - the problem is clear without mentioning the source and the answer is correct regardless of the challenge.

Comment: I've got my torch. Who do I see about a pitchfork?

Comment: +1 Same argument as burninating [project-euler](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler) and [koans](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306253/a-moan-about-koans?lq=1).

Comment: See also [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and [Code Puzzling and Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) beta sites.

Comment: +1 Oh, you asked that yesterday already

Comment: They are all gone now! We are freeeeeee!

Comment: @Thomas That's why I'm asking, if we leave it it will be tagged by more.. Kill them before they lay eggs.

Comment: @Anders Did you flag to close the bad [codingbat] questions?

Comment: @approxiblue I mean the tags are gone, not the questions. I flagged one that was off topic, though.

Answer (score 38):

Much like Project Euler is no longer here, it should not be here.

[image: Trogdor]

Comment: I've said this on past occasions, and I don't have much hope of the community ever sharing my view, but I'm still opposed to the kneejerk purging of problem set tags. They can have real value - some people are experts in *those precise problem sets* because they've solved them, and want to be able to find and answer questions about them. Certainly one of the first things I did after completing the Ruby Koans was look for questions relating to them on Stack Overflow. I don't know whether this particular tag is useful, but being a problem set tag doesn't automatically make it worthless.

Comment: @MarkAmery:  Use the [meta tag test](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).  Can a question exclusively tagged with codingbat survive?  Probably not, since most questions concerning Codingbat involve a language or two.  Also, most of the questions being asked *could* be considered on-topic and highly useful for those looking to solve the problems in a given language.  While I see no value in the tag itself, the questions have *some* value here.

Comment: This is somewhat off-topic, but after reading the original "Death of Meta Tags" post from 2010 (which used "subjective", "best-practices" and "beginner" as example tags), I wonder if purging of "codingbat", "project-euler" and similar tags is _really_ in the spirit of that post?