# I challenge the [kattis] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, meta-tags

The [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kattis/info) for [kattis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kattis) says it all:

> Use this tag for programming challenges found on Kattis.com.

> [Kattis](https://open.kattis.com/) is a website where you can find hundreds of programming problems to solve.  Kattis is used for competitions internationally, through organizations such as the [International Collegiate Programming Contest (ICPC)](https://icpc.baylor.edu/).

This is a meta tag that we don't want. Let's burn it! Like many similar ones before it:

- [Burninate Project Euler](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275935/1048572)
- [The [freecodecamp] fire?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351159/1048572)
- [Make love, not [codewars]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412155/1048572)
- [Can we remove the Codility meta tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404309/1048572)
- [Is the [code.org] tag meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365874/1048572)
- [We need to de-leet [leetcode]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399117/1048572)
- [The challenge of burninating [hackerrank]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359866/1048572)
- [Should we blacklist [hackerrank]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359879/1048572)
- [Is it time for [codingbat] to fly away?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308951/1048572)
- [A moan about [koans]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306253/1048572)

There are currently 44 questions with the [kattis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kattis) tag.  One person has answered 8 questions; another has answered 3; one person has asked 3 questions.  No questions with the tag have been asked or answered in the last 30 days.

Comment: For context, I assume this comes from a recent question I also saw. Which is endemic to all the challenge sites: "I have <requirement> I produced <code that conforms> However, I'm told it doesn't work in some hidden test cases. Why?" Which is exceptionally difficult to answer. If the code looks correct, then *it could be* that the tests are wrong. Some of the challenges do have a problem where they reject legitimate solutions with slightly flawed tests. That's also not the only problem they have, either. Ultimately, if a question *is fit for SO*, doesn't matter if it came from a challenge.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, indeed I just removed the tag from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71008223/1048572). However, "*you implemented the algorithm correctly*" might be a valid answer, not veering into "*we can't tell either what the hidden tests do*" unanswerable territory.

Comment: Yeah,  it is a clear meta tag, burn it to hell and beyond. It also satisfies the criteria for expedited burnination

Comment: @OlegValter Even the [abbreviated burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/1048572) requires to "*have conferred with at least one other trusted community member*", and I prefer doing that through meta questions not transient chat. Also wouldn't know where this ranks on the "pointless edits" vs "actively does harm" scale - although VLAZ' comment shows that it can indeed be harmful.

Comment: @Bergi of course - just expressing approval of the request - the tag is indeed harmful as it invites code challenge questions which are off-topic on Stack Overflow *unless* the core of an issue is a programming *problem* (practical and all that). And in those cases, the tag does not help describe what the question is really about - so it is, without a shred of doubt, a meta tag

Comment: Personally, I wish we *did* have these tags.  We get dozens of questions from, say, hackerrank every day.  Not all of these questions end up being quite inappropriate enough to get closed and deleted.  I'd love it if they could all be tagged, so that I could more easily ignore them.  But it is not to be.

Comment: This `[kattis]` a candidate for neutering

Comment: Though this burninate is a great directory of coding challenge sites.

Comment: @Bergi For me it makes sense to have the tag. Other people that solved the same problem might be able to help.

Comment: @SteveSummit You're suggesting a unified `code-challenges` tag?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since this had ample precedent, not a lot of questions, and overwhelming Meta votes, I just burninated it.

Comment: Thanks. I was about to write an answer that says "*If everyone who upvoted the question had removed the tag from one single question, it would have been gone by now - twice*" :-)

Comment: Yeah, the huge number of votes is odd! Maybe it's because of the survey/the sunsetting jobs & dev story posts?

Comment: Someone created this tag again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kattis has 18 questions now.

Answer (score -6):

So here are my 2 cents: [competitive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_programming) is its own discipline and I believe Stack Overflow should be a suitable place for questions relating to it. Some aspects of competitive programming are different from normal software engineering. For example, you might have to think of test cases if hidden ones are failing, 'shortcuts' to get the code running correctly fast are encouraged and yes, for training you have to interact with systems such as Kattis.

I was actually able to [solve a particular problem I was having with Kattis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71027045/optimize-union-find-disjoint-set-union-implementation) today.

In my eyes the tag makes sense. Other people solving Kattis-specific problems might have solved the same challenge and ran into the same problem or failing test cases.

Comment: Stack Overflow, however, is not a site made to solve artificial coding challenges. It is a site to solve "practical, detailed questions" (from the [tour]) that are "practical, answerable problem[s] that [are] unique to software development" (from the [help/on-topic]). Note the emphasis on "practical".

Comment: @HereticMonkey Notice the OR between those sentences.

Comment: Notice the and before the quoted bullet...

Comment: Fair enough. But I'd say answers for competitive programming problems are still practical solutions to a problem, even though they are not directly applicable to some real-life practical situation. Case in point: questions about Rust are also allowed even though there is no practical use case for the language yet (or or other esoteric languages).

Comment: What do you mean "there is no practical use for the language yet"? Is that a joke?

Comment: https://www.rust-lang.org/production/users Considering npm uses Rust in "performance critical bottlenecks", I think you might want to walk back that statement.

Comment: They can be practical solutions to an artificial question. So if you can ask the question as a "practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development", you won't need to mention Kattis. The fact that the problem comes from Kattis is irrelevant to the problem or its solution, just like the fact that a problem coming from homework comes from homework is irrelevant. Just ask the question; don't add other junk to it that isn't immediately relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: It's not as if your issue is kattis-specific either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371238/why-is-reading-lines-from-stdin-much-slower-in-c-than-python
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162367/significance-of-ios-basesync-with-stdiofalse-cin-tienull

Comment: FWIW, most of the questions were on-topic and [can still easily be found](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=kattis+is%3Aq&searchOn=3) (as you've noticed, your question is perfectly fine). We don't care why you are asking the question, only if it's inside the site's scope.

Comment: @yivi Haha! Yes. ;-) Machavity: Thanks. All good.