# Blacklist the [SPOJ] tag (and other online code judge/contest engines) please

Tags: discussion, blocklist-request

I've been burninating the [spoj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spoj) tag today again (there were only 4 questions, so no big deal). I remember doing that somewhere back in time, when it was a harder job.

Could we please blacklist tags in general, that are asking about Online Code Judging/Contest Engines at Stack Overflow. They shouldn't be able to be created/established for all future.

These kind of questions are notoriously bad, mostly because of missing MCVE's and using strange lingo like

- *gives me WA*
- *gives me TLE*
- ...

which haven't a reasonable meaning for anyone.

The inner workings of these engines aren't disclosed, and even not the test cases applied are in most cases.

Also these rarely will help in future research about real world programming problems, rather than just get how to cheat these engines by grabbing an answer from Stack Overflow.

I've also checked if [uva](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uva), [codechef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codechef) or [code-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-project) have been raised again. Fortunately I found they were not, but I'm not sure these are already blacklisted.

Comment: I totally support this, even though I don't know what spoj is, because it just sounds really gross.

Comment: @Don'tPanic TBH _SPOJ_ sounds the same as when I'm going to puke ;)

Comment: I spoj'd m'pants

Comment: It (and many others) were burninated here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler.

Comment: @Will I appreciate **your** contribution in particular!! :D Flagged Up

Comment: @davidism My point is more to blacklist these kind of tags also, such they can never be created again.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ completely agree, the link was just for the full list of tags.