# Formula student tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Could anyone with enough reputations create a Formula student tag? This will be good for all formula students in the world.

Comment: Tags are used to categorize questions, not askers...

Comment: What is a 'Formula student'?

Comment: @Cool https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_Student `Formula Student is a student engineering competition held annually in the UK. Student teams from around the world design, build, test, and race a small-scale formula style racing car.` That does make *slightly* more sense than just creating a tag for a type of student - but it's still very unlikely to be a good tag for Stack Overflow. There are loosely related precedents I think with coding competitions (project Euler comes to mind) but this would really need to make a much stronger and detailed case to even consider it.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Ok, but how is it related to programming?

Comment: @CoolGuy I didn't say it is. `this would really need to make a much stronger and detailed case to even consider it.`

Comment: Here is a link about [project euler](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler/284302#284302) and how that got burninated

Comment: how is this tag gonna be helpful/usefull?

Comment: Absolutely unclear what this "formula student" supposed to mean. Please explain what this is and provide links to 3-5 questions that would benefit from this tag.

Answer (score 6):

Tags are not just created because they might be useful. Tags are created when they apply to an *existing* question - for example, I have enough reputation to create a tag, so I could create a new tag when I ask a question if it were necessary.

To create a tag, there needs to be an existing question that the tag would apply to. Bear in mind also that tags that only apply to very few questions aren't actually that useful and tend to get removed again.

Comment: This is all true. Suppose the OP offers a link to a question that is about the subject mentioned by the OP, do you create the tag?

Comment: This seem to be comment... Answer does not address whatever tag proposed in the question (assuming you know and can explain what tag OP is asking for)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov No, this is an answer. "Can someone create X tag?" -- "No, because <reasons>".

Comment: I do not understand what you guys are talking about. If you do not know what formula student is you should research it before you criticise me not being specific. And I was told by the staff from stackoverflow to ask such a question. 
Stop criticising, this is not I want. I want help by someone telling me where I should post such a question or who I need to speak to. Thanks

Comment: @ChaoLI I haven't criticised you. This answer is just an explanation of why we can't do what you're asking at the moment. If you can demonstrate that there's a need for the tag with a link to (preferably multiple) questions that would benefit from it, then someone can add it. Since you haven't provided that, it won't get done. Additionally, the burden of research here is on you, not us. Please add links to your question to explain what formula student is.

Comment: @ChaoLI *[...]I was told by the staff[...]*... May I ask where/when you were told that?