# The [freecodecamp] fire?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I found the [freecodecamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/freecodecamp) tag, which does not seem to have any usage guidance (in the wiki description) nor does it say anything regarding the tagged questions. For example, [How can I complete these requirements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44556684/how-can-i-complete-these-requirements) and [PHP and server connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679953/php-and-server-connection).

It is clearly a **meta tag** which includes questions from JavaScript, PHP, etc. The common factor seems to be that the users are working on some project related to [freeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.com/).

Can this tag be burninated?

Comment: [Here's your flamethrower](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhGG7.gif).  Use it well.

Comment: *slowclap*. I'm having real difficulty with coming up with a better title for this burnination request.

Comment: I'm changing all of my passwords from correct horse battery staple to this. This is perfect.

Comment: Very related: [We burned \[project-euler\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler)

Comment: @ryanyuyu well it seems to be back [tag:project-euler]

Comment: There is no black list of the tag at the end of a burinate process?.

Comment: @DragandDrop https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120642/347191 blacklist I guess is a different process..

Comment: @suraj I've removed the tag (again) and pined the editor who added it to let them know.

Comment: Yeah, a fire camp! I bring 2 kg of Marshmallow. I just can't wait for the spooky story time. Can you give me the adress again?

Comment: Hey! I had a tag score of 7 in that tag! _/ironic pout_

Comment: Ok this explains the wiki edit someone tried to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16525590), which I rejected and told them to make make a burninate-request instead. Turns out there is one already. And indeed blacklist all tags that have already been burninated, so we stop wasting everyone's time like this.