# Should we blacklist [hackerrank]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, blocklist-request

This is the follow up of [The challenge of burninating [hackerrank]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359866/the-challenge-of-burninating-hackerrank).

TLDR [hackerrank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hackerrank) is harmful, and should not exist.

Counting [Burninate Project Euler](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler), [hackerrank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hackerrank) has been burninated at least twice now. It could be easily forseen that further attempts to use the tag are inevitable as long as the site exists.

Should we [blacklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239189/how-should-we-make-tag-blacklist-requests/239192#239192) the tag?

### Progress

A consensus have been reached, the tag should be blacklisted. The post has been flagged for moderator attention, so grab a cool beverage of your choice ;)

Comment: What has been the rationale previously, for Project Euler etc? Is the tag too specific? Could we have `online-coding-challenge`? (In terms of grouping similar questions together, I think a general tag would be OK).

Comment: Also, Can you outline, in your question, why you believe this tag to be harmful?

Comment: @halfer The rationale is that these tags only describe the _origin_ of the question, rather than the question itself.

Comment: Thanks @duskwuff. I am quite neutral about it, but is my tag suggestion above worth considering as an alternative? That describes the kind of question it is, and not its origin.

Comment: @halfer No, "online coding challenge" is still just describing where a question came from. Consider a question about reversing a linked list, for instance -- it could be from a coding challenge, or from someone's homework, or a practical question, but it's still the same question either way.

Comment: @duskwuff: fair enough, but should the criteria not be "is the tag useful?". I imagine someone would want to use these tags to browse coding challenge questions (perhaps with the intention of answering them, I don't know).

Comment: @halfer See the tag wiki for [meta-tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta-tags) and [the SO blog post to which it links](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/). In short, the general consensus (and official stance of SO) is that these tags should be dedicated to Trogdor with fire.

Comment: It is maybe one of those cases where describing the origin of a problem can be as useful, and maybe give better results than describing the problem itself. If someone is looking for something very specific, from hackerrank, they can probably find it by sifting through these results.

Comment: There is a similar tag used for a certain line of C classes, [tag:cs50]. We'll want to include that in this discussion as well. I don't have any strong feelings for this one either way. I understand why it exists, even if it goes against the meta-tag policies.

Comment: @halfer The intention of this post is simple: blacklist or no. That the tags are bad were already discussed in previous posts, and were taken as a given.

Comment: @JeffMercado I don't know if combining multiple blacklist posts into a single one a good idea. I agree [tag:cs50] looks pretty much the same thing and should be burninated. Given its size, it won't be that easy though

Comment: I'm not necessarily saying we should make a list of things to kill, just that whatever decision is applied here could easily be applied with that one too and the other way around. They are very much in the same spirit as far as tag use goes.

Comment: *"A consensus have been reached, the tag should be blacklisted."* Huh? First, I have to admit to being 100% ignorant of the actual question. Nonetheless, where's the *consensus*? 12 comments? 5 commenters, not including yourself? What's the actual issue? And sure, what's your agenda? (And absolutely, what's your concern and how is this some kind of consensus?) Blacklisting something *sounds* pretty major... and extreme. What am I missing?

Comment: @JeffMercado [tag:cs50] at least has _some_ implications for the content of the question -- there's a specific support library that's used for the C portion of the course, for instance.

Comment: Ok. I read the various links - which BTW I'd think the actual context would have been part of your question - and still wonder what's the actual issue? I get you have a bias against code challenge site (and maybe so do I). But... I *still* wonder how (a) both of your posts on MSO along with (b) one answer and... a few comments makes for a *consensus*. It doesn't make enough sense for me.

Comment: @dfd Agreement is indicated by votes. I read it as a consensus when 16 hours later >90% people agreed and no one made any counterargument, which you are more than welcome to do so down in the answer section. In light of lacking reasons _not_ to do so, and the reasons laid out in the question, I think it appropriate not to postpone indefinitely

Comment: @dfd The case for blacklisting is very simple really: given that the tag is harmful, as discussed in other posts, __and__ it is repeatedly misused, as demonstrated by multiple burnination attempts, we should blacklist it to avoid wasting the time fixing it again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), thanks to our CMs. Any new question which uses that tag, would display a red error banner, and the poster will not be able to submit their question:

[image]

Comment: For completeness: the link in the popup in the screenshot is [see meta for details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler).