# No custom page for non-existing tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request

While reading this [hot meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359879/should-we-blacklist-hackerrank?cb=1), I became curious as to what kind of question falls under [hackerrank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hackerrank), so I opened it in a new tab.

I thought that my Internet connection is slow because no questions appeared, but in reality there are really no question under it, either because there are really no questions tagged with it or the tag itself does not exist.

Is there a reason why non-existing tags do not have any custom **Not Found** page?

*For assurance, I tried typing a random tag, but it's just the same, no custom page*:

[image]

Comment: It might have existed or exist shortly after you load that page though (leaving aside syns and tag merges). It's not a case of "not found" - more a "does not currently exist and thus 0 results found".

Comment: It's still weird - for me, it looks [like this](https://screenshots.firefox.com/E7R9Mwx3VBLaGk63/stackoverflow.com), with an image and text clearly indicating that no results were found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not browsing the page for a tag, you're executing a search that returns 0 results. Showing a 404 Not Found would be strange and wrong.

The page for a tag is `https://stackoverflow.com/tags/{tagname}/info`, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hackerrank/info. That page does return a 404 Not Found for tags that don't exist.