# Make love, not [codewars]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Related: *[Can we remove the Codility meta tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404309/can-we-remove-the-codility-meta-tag)*

We now have a [codewars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codewars) tag, which has 8 questions. This should be removed for the same reason that [codility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codility) was removed: this really isn't a programming topic, it's a platform. The fact that it's a [Codewars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codewars) problem tells me nothing about what the actual topic is.

Can we remove this?

Comment: Plenty of those https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359866/the-challenge-of-burninating-hackerrank, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351159/the-freecodecamp-fire

Comment: @JeanneDark did you [tag:mean] [tag:make] love, not [tag:war]? :)

Comment: As long as we don't remove the [clone wars](https://code.org/starwars)

Comment: To be honest, if people would apply the tag more thoroughly it would seem very useful – for ignoring such questions.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi well, that would be anyways a misuse of the tags, since tags are meant to connect experts with questions they are interested in answering, not in ignoring.

Comment: Join us in the following episode next week: burninate [[tag:kattis]]!

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yep, that one needs to go too.

Comment: "There are no questions tagged [love]"!

Comment: @einpoklum did you forget where we are? :) There is only [tag:coffee] and [tag:war]

Comment: Make coffee not bugs? Unless love is the name your make file, I suppose.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While I agree that it does not add much to a question, it actually does add something, because to answer those questions, you often have to understand the [Codewars API](https://dev.codewars.com/#users-api)

However, as Braiam pointed out in comments, it should then be [codewars-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codewars-api) instead. Some of them could possibly be retagged.

But I seriously doubt the value of any of them. Burn it.

Comment: If we need a  tag for the codewars api, we create a codewars api tag, not a generic.

Comment: There is currently only one question left with the `codewars` tag (the only one that is not going to Roomba soon, that is). I don't know if one question justifies a new tag. But anyway, the way I see it, this is one of those tags we will have a hard time getting rid of/moderate. Even with the proposed new tag, obviously users will just use it to their "problem from codewars" questions and in the worse case - it will just be recreated soon enough...