# Blacklist the [project-euler] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, blocklist-request

The tag [project-euler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-euler) was [already burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler) but it keeps getting re-created.

It was recently re-added to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200236/project-euler-15). If you look at the question history the last few edits are just adding and removing the tag.

Comment: Same for all the other _"code-judge"_ engines too please. These seem to generate a recognizable amount of VLQ questions popping up in Stack Overflow.

Comment: There were only a couple of them, so it was an easy clean-up, but that rash does seem likely to keep coming back.

Comment: Looks like one person was responsible for adding this tag back. Tag wikis were also suggested, but those have been dealt with. Blacklisting does not seem to be imminently necessary, but I guess it couldn't hurt.

Comment: @CodyGray: I have the `project-euler` tag feed in my RSS reader because it keeps returning from the dead from time to time. It really is time to blacklist this one.